# Traducir consulta SQL a eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin, eloquent

Estoy intentando copiar una consulta de SQL a eloquent pero hay una linea que no me esta funcionando, es la linea del where

Codigo que funciona en SQL

```
SELECT solicitudes.id, solicitudes.titulo, fallas.nombre, US.name, UE.name, estados.nombre FROM solicitudes 
    LEFT JOIN fallas ON fallas.ID = solicitudes.id_falla 
    LEFT JOIN users as US ON US.id = solicitudes.id_solicitante 
    LEFT JOIN users as UE ON UE.id = solicitudes.id_encargado 
    LEFT JOIN historico_solicitudes ON historico_solicitudes.id_solicitud = solicitudes.id 
    LEFT JOIN estados ON estados.id = historico_solicitudes.id_estado WHERE historico_solicitudes.actual = 1
```

---

Codigo que no funciona en la cláusula where, ya que si la quito esta me muestra el resultado esperado

```
return $query ->leftjoin('fallas', 'fallas.id', 'solicitudes.id_falla')
    ->leftjoin('equipos_mant', 'equipos_mant.id', 'solicitudes.id_equipo')
    ->leftjoin('users as usuario_encargado', 'usuario_encargado.id', 'solicitudes.id_encargado')
    ->leftjoin('users as usuario_solicitante', 'usuario_solicitante.id', 'solicitudes.id_solicitante')
    ->leftjoin('historico_solicitudes', 'historico_solicitudes.id_solicitud', 'solicitudes.id_encargado')
    ->leftjoin('estados', 'historico_solicitudes.id_estado', 'estados.id')
    ->where('historico_solicitudes.actual', '=', 1)
    ->select('solicitudes.id as id', 'solicitudes.titulo as titulo', 'fallas.nombre as falla', 'usuario_encargado.name as nombre_encargado', 
    'usuario_solicitante.name as nombre_solicitante', 'equipos_mant.id as id_equipo', 'estados.nombre as estado');
```

Comment: Cuando lo dejas así marca algún error? o simplemente no trae datos?

Comment: No me tare datos, cabe destacar que si tengo datos que cumplen la condicion.

Comment: el campo actual es numérico o boleano?

Comment: Cuando lo cree lo hice como booleano pero cuando se creo me lo dejo como tinyint(1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fue un error de codigo ya que estaba buscando algo completamente distinto

```
->leftjoin('historico_solicitudes', 'historico_solicitudes.id_solicitud', 'solicitudes.id_encargado')

->leftjoin('historico_solicitudes', 'historico_solicitudes.id_solicitud', 'solicitudes.id')
```